# Is it insecure to make the CPanel username same as domain name?

Tags: security, cpanel

If I set my cPanel username same as domain name, then everybody already knows my cPanel username. Does it pose security risk?

Comment: I would say so. Usernames and passwords should never be easily guessed.

Comment: Yes , Better you set username something different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set your cPanel username as the same as your domain name, but people may not know that this is what you're doing if you do that unless you tell them specifically that's what you're doing.

If people know what your username is, you've just made half of the guessing work done for possible hackers. It's quite common that the username will be the first eight letters of the domain name. For example, if your domain name was abccompany.com, chances are good that the default username will be **abccompa** or **abccompany** and hackers will try this along with the common dictionary word passwords like "baseball" or "password123".

Most web hosts encourage their clients to use a random username to make it more difficult to guess the username and password. So it is not recommended to make your cPanel username the same as your domain name.

Source: I owned a web hosting company for the past 16 years.

Answer (score -3):

Of course. If you do so, you'll make hacking process easier.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on why you think this is the right answer? We really want detailed answers with references, not just one-liners with no backing evidence.